# i don't know what i get an error related to DTO when i want generate a wcf test from a log file

Tags: c#, wcf, testing, automated-tests

I hava a wcf log file and in visual studio there is an option to generate a wcf test with this file, the problem comes up when i choose a method and click next, it throws the next error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per  error message, your business entity `Scisa.Focys.Business.Entitites.STO.PersonSearchFilterDTO` should have attribute `[DataContract]` or `[MessageContract]`, that is missing.

Comment: but is not supposed that the defaul engine for serialization (DataContractSerializer) do that for default. anyway i did another wcf service that sends DTO, and it work perfectly even when i not define these annotations, but the diference is that in this second test i use a client to create the wcf test instead of the wcf trace file.

Comment: Check if any attribute of `PersonSearchFilterDTO` is missing `[DataMember]` OR `[EnumMember]` if enum.

Comment: Also there is one option while generating proxies/wsdl to automatically generate messageContract wrapper over primitive types. Might be its changed this time.